# Upgrading and existing flex application using the mx library to work on Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am trying to make my flex app work on Android, and that involves making an AIR app to run on Android. Seeing as the flex app needs the mic, an AIR app is required. I am using flash builder 4.5 on win7 with air 2.6. The trouble seems to be that most of it is now not available. For example mx.containers is there, but not mx.containers.viewStack. I notice that there are obvious equivalents in spark for some components but not others. 
VBox, HBox, Canvas VDividedBox, AdvancedDataGrid and associated custom renderers are the components my application uses the most. 
What is the fastest way to make this work on Android, I am under time pressure. Is there a site somewhere that recommends the best way to do this, and what components can be replaced with which?

(This is my first time posting here, but I have a good reputation on vworker:
http://www.vworker.com/RentACoder/DotNet/SoftwareBuyers/ShowBuyerInfo.aspx?lngAuthorId=6446927)

Thanks

Thor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to read the [Full Adobe Manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/index.html) for Flex 4.5.  Much of it will be review and you can breeze through that, but you'll want to learn about the Spark components and the spark architecture.

To draw a direct parallel to your specific components you need:

A Canvas is, generally, replaced by a Group.

a VBox is replaced with a VGroup.  Or you can use a Group with a VerticalLayout.

An HBox is replaced with an HGroup.  Or you can use a Group with a HorizontalLayout.

There is no Spark version of a ViewStack.  In Mobile Applications you'd probably use the view class and ViewNavigator to accomplish something similar

I'm not sure of a VDividedBox; nor AdvancedDataGrid replacement.

Since you wan to build an Android app, next you're going to want to read [this Adobe manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/index.html).  To get acceptable performance out of AIR for Android, you are probably going to have to rewrite an MX heavy project from scratch.

This is not a project I'd want to partake with tight time constraints; so I wish you best of luck.

Comment: It should also be noted that you don't use viewstacks on mobile apps, but use Views instead.  I definitely recommend that you research more about mobile dev since what you've used in Flex in the past will definitely won't work on mobile.  Performance is key.

Comment: Oops, my bad.  I missed his mention of ViewStacks.

Comment: Thank, not the answers I was hoping for, but a good one nonetheless.